# Bluetooth power source RF circuit

Tags: power-supply, bluetooth

I am trying to design an RF circuit/ a PCB that has Bluetooth functions for transmitting data. I am looking at how to integrate this into a power source. I am quite new to this and not too sure how to get started. Are there any references or examples that can help me get started?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Surely you want to integrate the power source into your device? You have left out all sorts of details such as voltage, current, battery / mains, etc. Power supply would be considered fairly trivial stuff compared with designing RF for > 2 GHz. Are you sure you've chosen a good project to attempt? In any case, the question is rather broad and you probably need to add focus to it to avoid closure.

Comment: Thanks for the resposne! I am still in the design stage. I want to design circuit that is capable of measuring the force data (eg. from strain gauge) and the data is needed somehow to be stored. I want to transfer the data using Bluetooth. I am not too sure its that is specific enough.. I am trying to brainstorm a bit while also seeking some advice that can help me get started.

Comment: (1) Buy someone else's Bluetooth module. (2) Work out what voltage and current it requires. (3) Work out what voltage the strain gauge requires. See if it can be the same as (2). (4) Buy or design a suitable power supply.